# 3.7v > 3.3v voltage stepdown with logic-driven on/off control [paused]

Tags: digital-logic, rs232, dc-dc-converter, low-power, control

***(PAUSED)**: This topic is currently on hold as I source necessary hardware.*

I need to connect a Wi-Fi/RS232 module to a low-powered monitoring device, and for maximum portability, I'd like to power the Wi-Fi module - which runs off 3.3v at a peak of 250mA - from the 3.7v/1200mAh Li-Po battery built into the device itself.

To do so, I first need to drop the voltage from 3.7v to 3.3v in a way that can tolerate 250mA. I figure a series resistor should be sufficient, since I'm just running off a battery and not an unregulated power source - but what value resistance should I use?

In addition, the Wi-Fi module's own low power/standby state draws 8mA, which is relatively low but still noticeable, and would drain the battery over time. I've managed to unearth some undocumented info on how to tweak a couple of unused sense inputs that wire straight into the device's CPU (one via a 100Ω series resistor, the other via a 330Ω one) so they work as output lines, and I'd like to use one of these to switch power to the module on/off (possibly via a transistor or something...?). [I need to verify this, but I'm 99% sure the output before the resistors is standard 3.3v TTL.]

Everything needs to fit inside a compartment 50x54mm in size, *approximately* 4-5mm thick.

My *non*-SMD soldering skills are passable, but I've never worked with SMD components, so I need non-SMD solutions.

I also need an solution that radiates virtually zero RFI/EMI due to the electromagnetically sensitive medical environment the device will be used in, which won't tolerate even low levels of continuous EMI/RFI radiation particularly well (although short Wi-Fi bursts will be fine).

Answer (score 4):

A series resistor will not provide a good power supply for the WiFi module, as the voltage drop will vary depending on the current consumption of the module, which will vary.

Instead look at voltage regulator chips, "low-dropout" variety. Some are equipped with an enable line and sleep mode.

Comment: I agree.  Low-dropout regulators (LDO's) are very quiet by nature, whereas buck converters take work to keep them quiet.  LDO's are inefficient compared to bucks, but since you're only dropping from 3.7 to 3.3V, the inefficiency won't hit you that hard...

Comment: Indeed. 0.4 V * 250 mA = 0.1 W dissipation from the regulator. Nothing to worry about really. The thermal mass of the ground plane that the tab is connected to is probably sufficient to sink that heat.

Comment: I found some possible candidate through-hole LDO regulators at Digi-Key: http://tinyurl.com/ldo8k5y - would any particular one of these these be especially appropriate?

Comment: The MCP1700-3302 with a dropout voltage of 0.178v looks like a good find.

Comment: I've been having a look at the various regulators out there, but the parametric search engines I've used so far (Mouser, Linear, TI, Digi-Key) don't provide a "has enable pin/line/bar" metric, making it hard to filter for that feature. How might I search for an enable-pin-equipped through-hole LDO regulator, or could I add other components to switch the LDO on/off?

Comment: @i336_   
You'd need to add a P-channel MOSFET between the 3.7v input from the battery and the LDO. (Source pin connected to 3.7v battery, Drain pin connected to LDO.) Put a 400K or so resistor between Source and Gate (which will keep it normally off). Grounding the Gate pin with an open-drain output will turn it on.

Comment: I see. Let me just qualify... **1)**, I do indeed want the MOSFET connected to the battery (obviously), but the GPIO output will, as far as I know, sit around +3.3v when on (I'm not sure how it will behave when off). Will this be a problem? **2)**, just to qualify, what would define an "open-drain output"? **3)**, if such a high resistance (400k) is needed to keep the MOSFET off, would the GPIO line with the 100Ω resistor on it (refer the question) be the best choice, or should I use the line with the 330Ω one?

Comment: @i336_ Usually GPIO outputs can be defined as either push-pull or open-drain.  In the first case, the output is driven either 3.3v or ground.  For open-drain, it is either tristated or ground.  Since you have the 400k  pullup to 3.7v, you don't need to drive the output high.  Check your microcontroller's I/O section on how to configure pins for open-drain.  You don't need either a 100Ω or 300Ω resistor in series with the output, this is not like driving a BJT where you need a base resistor.  However neither value will cause a problem.

Comment: I see. I'll take a look at the microcontroller's documentation; a brief scan gives me the impression I can indeed control that kind of thing. Thanks very much for your help! It's been good to figure out how I would achieve this design, but I think I'm at the point where I need to actually start purchasing and tinkering with hardware :). I'll come back to this question once the hardware is in hand and I've poked at it a bit.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a buck-boost converter.  For example, the LTC3530EMS will take any input voltages from 1.8v to 5.5v, and you can set it to have an output of 3.3v.  If the voltage is above 3.3v, it will drop it down ("buck"), if the voltage is below 3.3v, it will boost it up.  That way, if your battery voltage drops below 3.3v, you can still power your electronics.

Most of these devices are relatively difficult to solder, with pins under the package.  Unfortunately none of them come in DIP packages.  However the LTC3530EMS, [available from Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LTC3530EMS%23PBF/LTC3530EMS%23PBF-ND/1620105) comes in a 10-MSOP package which is relatively easy to deal with.

For prototyping, you can get an MSOP to DIP adapter from several places, [such as this one](http://www.proto-advantage.com/store/product_info.php?products_id=2200031).

If all you need is to drop the input voltage to 3.3v (based on your comment below), then you might consider the LM3671MF, which is buck-converter only.  It is also [available from Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LM3671MF-3.3%2FNOPB/LM3671MF-3.3%2FNOPBCT-ND/1590190) in a SOT-23 package which will be easier to solder.  Re EMI, yes it does have a 2 MHz oscillator, but I have used these devices in several medical grade devices and have never had an EMI problem with them, after rigorous testing.

There are also SOT-23-5 to DIP adapters [available](http://www.proto-advantage.com/store/product_info.php?products_id=2200093).

Comment: Interesting solution - now I get why they're called buck converters :) - and thanks for the reference to the LTC3530EMS and particularly the prototyping adapter. The critical level of the device itself is actually 3.5v, so I don't need boost functionality. Also, unfortunately, I figured I was just asking for a series dropping resistor so I neglected to copy over the EMI/RFI requirements from the old post this one superseded (http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/103075/2xaaa-battery-3-3v-250ma-step-up-converter-with-logic-driven-power-control-s)! I've edited the question.

Comment: @i336_ I added information about a buck-only converter to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for that - although I must admit, I like your use of the phrase "*easier* to solder" :)... looking at the SOT-23 package size, I give my not-very-steady hands and low-powered soldering iron a 20% chance of managing to get wires soldered to it at all, and a -1% chance of soldering wires to it without the thing melting (think "take #52"...). I'm not set up to work with tiny/fiddly things yet... :P - *also, see comment posted to @gwideman's answer*